# Is there a way to trap the time remaining on a Windows API SetTimer event?

Tags: timer, vb6

I have successfully implemented a SetTimer Win API function in my VB6 program. The user can set any amount of delay in minutes in an INI file, before a folder is scanned and a procedure is executed.

I am wondering if there is a way to get the number of milliseconds (or minutes) remaining before the timer is ready to execute the procedure code?. For example, if the User has configured 20 minutes for the timer, the program will SetTimer interval to 20 mins. *60000 to convert it to milliseconds. At any time the User wants to know - "how long before the timer interval will be '0' for the procedure execution to commence?" Can anyone help with a suggestion?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: No, there is no API to query "How much time is left before my timer expires?". If you want to do so, you'll need to do yourself it in your code. For instance, instead of using a timer for the entire period, use a shorter interval and calculate the number of timer events that will need to fire before the interval expires. You can then count the events as they happen, and at any point calculate the remaining time (TotalDelay - (EventsAlready * EventPeriod) / EventPeriod).

Comment: Thanks that is a good suggestion - I will test this. Meanwhile I came up with another method which may be of interest to others - I will post it as soon as I finalize the code

Answer (score 0):

Store the time when you call SetTimer, and compare that time to the current time when the user asks for the remaining time.

To use the same format you could use the GetTickCount API

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private mlngStartTime As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Print "seconds remaining : " & CStr((mlngStartTime - GetTickCount) \ 1000)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  mlngStartTime = GetTickCount + 20 * 60000
End Sub
```

Comment: Great Thanks. I need to test this and see if it fits my need. Thanks for taking time to write the code for me. appreciate it.

Comment: Great Thanks. I need to test this and see if it fits my need. Thanks for taking time to write the code for me. appreciate it.